# how to change the state of the app when certain values are selected from a drop down menu?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I've created a drop down menu in a stateful widget and this is working great!

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return DropdownButton(
dropdownColor: kBlueGrey900,
value: selectedFaction,
items: factions.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String item) {
return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
value: item,
child: Text(
item,
style: TextStyle(
color: kWhite,
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
fontSize: 20,
fontFamily: 'SourceSansPro',
),
),
);
}).toList(),
onChanged:  (String? item) {
    setState(() {
      selectedFaction = item!;
    });
  },
),
```

what i don't understand is how to set the state of the app e.g. another widgets visibility depending on the users selection.
So if they choose number 6 in the factions list, I then want a bool used for a widgets visibility to change to true.

thanks so much

Comment: This shouldn't be that hard... you only need to create a flag like "bool _flag = false"; before your build method in your stateful widget and then, inside your **onChanged** method, before the **setState** call, make a condition that if the selected item is equal to 6, then change the _flag value to true. That is, of course, if you want to use "_flag" inside the same widget build tree. Otherwise, you would need to use packages that listen for value changes in other classes like provider, getx, bloc, etc.

Comment: I tried this in both the setstate and above it of the onchanged: method,

Comment: if(factions[6]){abilityRowVis = true;} and im gett the error Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'. on the factions[6] part

Comment: did you try my method ?

Comment: I actually used an if statement that linked it to the string variable for the text in the list. makes it easy to add to add to the list later out of order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways you can do this:

1. In case both the widgets (one with faction & one which you need to
   change the visibility) reside in same class, declare a parallel bool
   array of all falses at class level , the length of which will be same as faction.

   In faction onChange method, set state of that index (say 6) to true.

   Bind the second widget's visibility to the corresponding index in the    bool array.
2. In case both widgets reside in different pages/files. Declare a common
   file with name for example `ApplicationParams.dart`. Do all of the above (as in point 1) by declaring the bool array as static.
   Access the array for example `boolVisibilityArray` as `ApplicationParams.boolVisibilityArray`